# How to stop smadav from starting on boot completed?

Tags: windows, boot, anti-virus

I really do not know what is wrong with this software, I do not wish the program to launch after signing in so I decided to disable its startup from the startup section of the task manager. Still when I restarted the device, the smadav window keeps showing up. Can someone help force windows to tell this program to back down on startup? Its so annoying especially when it draws over important apps I use for productivity, Thank You. I cannot uninstall the app because it protects the system from dangerous executable from the internet by blocking them, I just want it not to draw any windows on startup.If it can start in the background, could be good for me.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.